# Use Go goto label on Err

Tags: go, label, goto

I want to use label to minimize err part like this:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    consul "github.com/hashicorp/consul/api"
    "os"
)
func main(){
    client,err := consul.NewClient(consul.DefaultConfig())
    if err != nil {
        goto Err
    }
    agent := client.Agent()
    checkReg := agent.AgentCheckRegistration{
        ID:   "test-check",
        Name: "test-check",
        Notes: "some test check",
    }
    if err = agent.CheckRegister(checkReg); err !=nil{
        goto Err
    }
Err:
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(2)
}
```

so i could have one place to put all the err handling in one place, but seems not working as

```
./agent.CheckRegister.go:10:8: goto Err jumps over declaration of checkReg at 
./agent.CheckRegister.go:13:19: agent.AgentCheckRegistration undefined (type *api.Agent has no field or method AgentCheckRegistration)
```

is there a way to use goto to make it work?

Comment: No, the error explains why. Predeclare everything, use conditional blocks, or a function where you can return early

Comment: @JimB alright, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the compiler is complaining is defined in the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Goto_statements):

> Executing the "goto" statement must not cause any variables to come
> into scope that were not already in scope at the point of the goto.
> For instance, this example:
>
> ```
>   goto L  // BAD  
>   v := 3
> L:
> ```
>
> is erroneous because the jump to label L skips the creation of v.

So you'll need to restructure your code. If you want to keep using `goto` here (as opposed to, say, `if-else` statements), then you'll have to move all the declarations up.

Note that you can split it like this:

```
   var v Type
   ...
L: ...
   v = FunctionThatReturnsType()
```

It should be OK to `goto L` here.